# Does twitter ban a certain set of Oauth Keys after rate limit hsa been exceeded too many times?

Tags: twitter, oauth

In our application, we have ran into a lot of problems with rate limit exceeded with Twitter. We put in a fix for that. It was working for a while, however it stopped working completely now. But if I use another set of OAUTH keys, it seems to bring back some tweets.

Could it be because the old set of Oauth keys are no longer working due to excessive rate limits exceeding?

Please advise.

Comment: are you checking the http status code and any returned error messages?

Comment: yes, I am, i put this in the debugger, and the returned error message is always rate limit has exceeded, this only happens with the old pair of Oauth keys though, not the newly generated keys. I want to know why